# Nusach of the 'nusach' tags

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Currently we have the following tags (and number of questions in each):

[nusach-ashkenaz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-ashkenaz) 14
[nusach-sefard](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-sefard) 7 (and the synonym [nusach-sfard](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-sfard))
[nusach-ari](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-ari) 5
[nusach-edot-hammizrach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-edot-hammizrach) 3

and

[nuschaot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuschaot) 53

Currently, the only questions utilizing more than one of those tags are:
[Differences between siddurim of the same nusach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16443/759)
[Friday Night Prayer before Maariv - Kegavnah or Bameh Madlikin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1562/759)
[When to say LeDovid HaShem Ori in a minyan with different nusach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9738/759)

I don't understand our situation. Most questions asked recently get placed in the newer group tag [nuschaot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuschaot) even if they are about one particular Nusach. Why do we have both specific and general categories, if the former aren't used?

What do *you* think should be done (or not done) about the current situation? How do you view each tag functioning in the future?

Comment: I note the possiblitly of creating a [tag:nusach-agnostic] tag (like SO's tag: [language-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)) but I'm not so thrilled with idea. If someone is, they may suggest it as an answer.

Comment: Why do we [tag:nuschaot] instead of [tag:nusach], by the way?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Plural vs singular? I don't know. Probably the whim of whoever first used it. (Which was me, IIRC.)

Comment: Is it really nusCHAot and not nusACHot?

Comment: @yoel, at least colloquially.

Comment: @yoel http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3832

Answer (score 1):

Keep the current tags. I envision the specific-*nusach* tags for questions about a prayer in a specific *nusach* (whether it's about wording/versions or not; e.g., a question on *p'shat* in the blessing "*Borchenu*" in *shm"a*)  and [nuschaot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuschaot) for questions about versions (e.g., saying "*Borchenu*" vs. "*Barech alenu*").

(Moreover, I think it's worth distinguishing questions about *Ashk'nazim*'s *nusach* "*S'farad*" from questions about *Ashk'nazim*'s *nusach* "*Ashk'naz*". And [arizal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arizal) is worth distinguishing from [nusach-ari](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-ari) IMO.)

Comment: With regards to your last point, this is no difficulty: you would tag "chasidus" for Sefard and "chabad" for Ari IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest collapse everything into [nuschaot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuschaot) and use general tags ([ashkenazi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashkenazi), [sephardi-mizrachi-eastern](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sephardi-mizrachi-eastern), [arizal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arizal), [yemenite-temani](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yemenite-temani) perhaps [chasidut-hasidism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chasidut-hasidism) or even a new one) where appropriate. To search for questions of a certain Nusach, you could search for two tags at once, such as: [`[nuschaot] [ashkenazi]`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuschaot+ashkenazi).

Part of the reason I suggest this is that many times questions deal with multiple nuschaot, all nuschaot or an unknown nusach. That is why a generalized tag seems best. Using all the individual tags would quickly clog the question (note there is a maximum of 5 tags per question).

It also allows for greater specificity, for example, if the question relates to a Chabad Nusach: just add [chabad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chabad).

Comment: I agree with this completely, with the sole nitpick that given this approach I think "nusach" makes more sense than the plural as a tag.