# Typo in tag nuschaot

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, retagging

Just realized there was a typo in the tag **nuschaot** - should be **nusachot**.

I am not sure how to change this and understand only a moderator or high-reputation user can do it. Also not sure it justifies a question on meta but don't know how else to raise this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that nuschaot is grammatically correct, as it is the term I most often hear when I listen to scholarly discussions on nusach.

Comment: You've raised this in an appropriate place. Can you document that the transliteration you propose is correct and that the existing one is not?

Answer (score 5):

The spelling ["נוסחאות" appears](//www.google.com/search?q=%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA+site%3Ahebrewbooks.org) many times on the Mi-Yodeya-beloved HebrewBooks site — many more times than ["נוסחות" does](//www.google.com/search?q=%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA+site%3Ahebrewbooks.org). (It also happens to be the plural I'm familiar with.) I think we should leave the tag as it, though map a synonym to it from [nusachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusachot) if there isn't one already.

> Also not sure it justifies a question on meta but don't know how else to raise this.

I think this was the ideal place and way to raise the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a simple typo but it turns out I was mistaken.

The official plural of nusah according to my modern Hebrew dictionary is nusahim

[image: nusah]

But indeed nuschaot is widely found and is also how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nusach) have it. Someone had asked the same question in a comment [on an earlier Meta question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/nusach-of-the-nusach-tags)

Must be coming from yiddish because I don't quite understand how you can build such a plural in modern Hebrew. But it is clearly correct.

Comment: See the next entry in that dictionary. It lists _nuschaos_ as the plural of _nuscha_. The definition it has for _nuscha_ is not relevant here, but perhaps there's another definition also.

Comment: @msh210 I checked with the (Israeli) magid shiur from my Sunday night halakha shiur. He said the plural of nusach is nusachim. Nuschaot means (mathematical) formulas. So at least I learned something from my original mistake !